# Why is the navigation stack hidden in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is the navigation stack private in Flutter? I am curious as to why the Flutter authors decided to make it hidden as a design choice.

For those interested, the navigation history is referenced as '_history' within NavigtorState.

```
class NavigatorState extends State<Navigator> with TickerProviderStateMixin, RestorationMixin {
    late GlobalKey<OverlayState> _overlayKey;
    List<_RouteEntry> _history = <_RouteEntry>[];
    final _HistoryProperty _serializableHistory = _HistoryProperty();
```

Side notes (looking for a response to above question):

Right now I am making a navigation observer that keeps track of the navigation stack using a queue. When push, pop, or remove are called, I update my queue accordingly. I solely use this to keep track of the depth of the navigation stack. This stack depth, combined with WillPopScope allows for me to fine tune when I want a user to be able to pop or not. Without getting into too much detail, I want my selected tab to not be popable to the root route (route: '/'). By knowing the depth is of length 1, I can use WillPopScope to stop a user from popping.

This circles me back to the original question; is keeping track of the stack a bad design choice for Flutter?

I have found limit resources as to *WHY* the flutter devs chose to make it private.

My one thought is to prevent users from manually editing the history. So why not allow for a public function such as getHistoryLength()?

Many thanks,

-Flutter Newbie

Comment: Check out [Navigator 2.0](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade), it is more complicated to setup, but it gives direct access to navigation stack and provides much more control.